# Can I extract comments of any page from https://www.rt.com/ using python3?

Tags: javascript, python, beautifulsoup, web-crawler

I am writing a web crawler. I extracted heading and Main Discussion of the this [link](https://www.rt.com/usa/353493-clinton-speech-affairs-silence/) but I am unable to find any one of the comment (Ctrl+u -> Ctrl+f . Comment Text). I think the comments are written in JavaScript. Can I extract it?

Answer (score 3):

RT are using a service from [spot.im](https://www.spot.im/) for comments

you need to do make two POST requests, first `https://api.spot.im/me/network-token/spotim` to get a token, then `https://api.spot.im/conversation-read/spot/sp_6phY2k0C/post/353493/get` to get the comments as JSON.

i wrote a quick script to do this

```
import requests
import re
import json

def get_rt_comments(article_url):
    spotim_spotId = 'sp_6phY2k0C' # spotim id for RT
    post_id = re.search('([0-9]+)', article_url).group(0)

    r1 = requests.post('https://api.spot.im/me/network-token/spotim').json()
    spotim_token = r1['token']

    payload = {
        "count": 25, #number of comments to fetch
        "sort_by":"best",
        "cursor":{"offset":0,"comments_read":0},
        "host_url": article_url,
        "canonical_url": article_url
    }

    r2_url ='https://api.spot.im/conversation-read/spot/' + spotim_spotId + '/post/'+ post_id +'/get'
    r2 = requests.post(r2_url, data=json.dumps(payload), headers={'X-Spotim-Token': spotim_token , "Content-Type": "application/json"})

    return r2.json()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    url = 'https://www.rt.com/usa/353493-clinton-speech-affairs-silence/'
    comments = get_rt_comments(url)
    print(comments)
```

Comment: Can I make these two requests for scraping any javascript material?

Comment: you don't need to worry about javascript, the method above will give you the comments in JSON format (this is the data that the javascript in the browser is using to display the comments). try running the script

Comment: 1. It returned a json. `comment.text` is not a method.
2. I want to do same (Comment Extraction) from `http://www.aljazeera.com/` . I read about phantomjs and phantompy. Can I use them for this purpose?

Comment: What it returns is the comments in JSON format, you just need to pick which attributes you want from it for example if you want the comment text you can do `[comment['content'][0]['text'] for comment in comments['comments']]`. 
If you want to extract data from multiple sites you will need to write a separate extractor for each site, while you can use phantomjs (or any other headless browser), it will be more effective and efficient to find what web requests are being made by the browser and copy those. in the case of aljazera there is a RSS feed for the comments associated with each article.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, if it can be viewed with a web browser, you can extract it.

If you look at the source it is really an iframe that loads a piece of javascript, that then creates a new  tag in the document with the source of that script tag loading bundle.js, which really contains the commenting software. This in turns then fetches the actual comments.

Instead of going through this manually, you could consider using for example webkit to create a headless browser that executes the javascript like an ordinary browser. Then you can scrape from that instead of having to manually make your crawler fetch the external resources.

Examples of such headless browsers could be [Spynner](https://github.com/makinacorpus/spynner), [Dryscape](https://github.com/niklasb/dryscrape), or the PhantomJS derived [PhantomPy](https://github.com/niwinz/phantompy) (the latter seems to be an abandoned project now).

Comment: I saw the `document,"//www.spot.im/launcher/bundle.js");` but where the file is? Can I go into that file for extracting the comments?

Comment: You need to download the file from the URL - your browser does that automatically as it references as the src of an iframe. The comments are not stored directly in that file, so you cannot extract the comments from there. It is only the code for handling the comments.

Comment: Can you refer me to some example that extracts something like comments? Any tutorial or code? I want to understand that how can it be done?

Comment: It's actually very simple as you do not need to click anything or "do" something on the page to get the comments to show. So basically you just load up the URL, and then based on a standard CSS selector, you extract the text you need. You can see an example here [Spynner](https://github.com/makinacorpus/spynner/blob/master/examples/ajax-test.py) which is just a few lines of code, but handles a more involved case where you need to click on things to make the text appear.