# Use Python script to scrape comments (Spot.IM)

Tags: python

I am trying to download about 6000+ comments from this [link](https://www.foxnews.com/politics/as-trump-heads-to-border-dems-double-down-on-manufactured-crisis-claim), which uses Spot.IM to manage the comments. I saw an earlier [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38607502/can-i-extract-comments-of-any-page-from-https-www-rt-com-using-python3) posted here that requires a Spot.IM token, but the token can only be given by the account manager (I presume it requires a paid account).

Is there any other way to download the comments without the need for a token?

Comment: Do you need performance in your scrap? If it isn't, you can try to use selenium to get the comment.

Comment: Nope, I don't need performance in my scrap. I'll try the solution that Pau and you suggested. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use a webdriver and Selenium for it.
You can follow this link to start:
https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/getting-started.html